# How to make a swf a link without the original fla file?

Tags: php, html, css, flash, hyperlink

Alright so I've got this swf that would be perfect as a button for my website, but the button is a swf, and I don't have the original fla file to edit where it redirects. Is there anyway to add a link to this button? *Note I've tried adding an additional image with a opacity of 0 above the swf, but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sothink SWF Decompiler](http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/) is able to convert the file to .fla format. I've used it for quite a few things before.

Having just tried to convert the button found [here](http://justxp.x10.mx/test/cta-play-free-now.swf) from .swf to .fla:

I tried it with the trial version and it exports it without the flames. The trial version doesn't export ActionScript so I presume there's something controlling the flames.

Whilst you are indeed unable to achieve the flame effect with CSS alone, it might be worth attempting a different button, or perhaps using an animated gif instead as it'll provide you with a button which is far easier to edit, and works on far more platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

**EDITED: now works in all major browsers:**

```
<style type="text/css">
    #playnow {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 9999;
    }
</style>

<div id="playnow">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
      data="http://justxp.x10.mx/test/cta-play-free-now.swf"
      width="209" height="37">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <p>Alternative content</p>
        <embed src="http://justxp.x10.mx/test/cta-play-free-now.swf"
          quality="high" bgcolor="#000000" width="209" height="37"
          name="button" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" play="true"
          loop="true" wmode="transparent"
          pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash">
        </embed>
    </object>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#playnow').on('mouseup', function() {
        window.location = "your/link";
    });​
</script>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kgeGP/6/

Comment: Edited my answer, give that a try.

Comment: Right, now it works (on Chrome at least). I'd suggest using `<span>` instead of `<div>` to wrap to the button width.

Comment: @irrelephant the `<div>` was based on the code on his website - `<span>` may be better, but I didn't look into how he's using the `<div>` in his layout.

Comment: Works on Chrome, but not on Firefox for me.

Comment: @nico Could be that the object was in z-indexed front of the parent container in Firefox, try this version: http://jsfiddle.net/kgeGP/3/

Comment: @Chris Clower: nope, no luck yet (FF14, Fedora 16)

Comment: Finally got it working in Firefox. Had to add the `wmode="transparent"` to prevent swfobject from capturing the DOM event. http://jsfiddle.net/kgeGP/6/

Answer (score 0):

Not really. The closest thing you can hope to achieve is:

Either have a `<a>` above the flash button, but that's probably not viable since you probably want some flashy hover animation?

Else you must have the `.fla`, and you could save it so that you can pass `$_GET`s to it. Like `example.com/button.swf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com`

You could try to import the `.swf` to a new `.fla` and see if you get what you're after.

But with modern CSS, you can as mentioned often recreate it through HTML only.

Comment: no it would be find to just have the link, it's already animated, the hover doesn't matter. How would I do the <a>

Comment: Or, you could just add a mouseup event to the parent container (see my answer and fiddle) :)

Answer (score 0):

Why use an swf for a button? You could probably achieve the same thing in css. And it would be quicker for loading, not to mention you have way more flexibility.

You could probably append a div around it and do some sort of jquery click function but thats messy and unreliable.

Comment: side note, perhaps link the swf so I can see if in my travels I have found something comparable in css

Comment: That button does have flashy hover animation. And this specific animation is probably unachievable in css.

Comment: That Button doesn't display on my device here...  : ) ...one more vote for finding a non-flash way to achieve your results.

Comment: i see. yea thats probably unbelievable in css. but i concur with chris's solutionj